# Vimwiki/Markdown blockquote syntax highlight

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown, plugin-vimwiki

AFAIK vimwiki's markdown syntax doesn't emphasize in any way blockquotes. I mean:

```
> This is a quote
```

is presented instead as simple text. For reading notes it can be confusing. So, how do you highlight both the `>` and the quote?

Comment: I'm pretty sure [https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) has highlighting for block quotes, if that's an option.

Comment: I've tried several colorschemes, both dark and light versions, and not a single one highlights either the `>` nor the whole block of text, @D.BenKnoble

Comment: I found no definition for `markdownBlockquote` in `https://github.com/blueshirts/darcula/blob/master/colors/darcula.vim`. It has only extra headers highlighting.

Comment: I realize that vimwiki's markdown syntax doesn't highlight it, and it's not affected by `markdownBlockquote' settings. I rephrased the question.

Comment: @Ludenticus dracula =/= darcula, but I'll delete my comment since it's markdown specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the behavior of syntax files. Create a file at .vim/syntax/after/markdown.vim with the contents:

```
"highlight the entire block quote
syn match Statement "^> .*"
```

Note 'Statement' can be any highlight group. You can see a list of highlight groups with `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim`)